# Images are not visible in child modal tabs - modal inside modal in MVC 5 .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

**In my MVC 5 website (bootstrap 4.3.1), I want to display modal inside existing modal to show thumbnail images.**
I am new to bootstrap and MVC so, I handled few events to show/hide tabs in child modal - second modal.

- Image area is showing during F12 inspect element but the actual image
  is not visible.
- If I try to edit the html in browser and add    something like
  `<label/>` or any random text inside div of the tab (parent of the image), then immediately image is visible.

Tried to search for zindex and monitored display: none/block but seems strange that image is not visible even though the area is getting used.

_Layout.cshtml has main modal.
**_DeviceTracker.cshtml partial view has the table of main modal, second modal plus below html and JS.**

Tried to apply various classes like 'modal-overlay' also but not working. display:block is being set on image and its parent but still its not visible for some reason. Also, there is no error in browser console. I have also attached screenshots of how it looks and rendered HTML.

Thanks for your help.

***ShowThumnail function will be called when user clicks on the thumbnail icon in main modal (from table in below HTML).***

**HTML**
    
        
            
    ....

```
<div class="modal fade" id="PressSheetThumbnailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PressSheetThumbnailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content modal-overlay">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="PressSheetThumbnailModalHeader">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body table-responsive" style="padding:5px;">
                    <div>
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist" id="ThumbnailTabPanel">
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content" id="ThumbnailTabContent" style="display: block;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#PressSheetThumbnailModal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DevicesActivity').DataTable({
            "filter": false,
            "paging": false
        });
    });

    function showThumbnail(wsid, jobid) {    
        $('#PressSheetThumbnailModalHeader').html(jobid + ' : ' + wsid);
        $('#ThumbnailTabPanel').empty();
        $('#ThumbnailTabContent').empty();    
        let prinectAPIResponse = FetchPressRoomManagerImages(wsid, jobid);
    }

    function FetchPressRoomManagerImages(wsid, jobid) {
            $.ajax({..
            },
            success: function (data) {
                ShowResponse(wsid, data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(xhr.status);alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
        });
    }

    function ShowResponse(wsid, data) {    
        if(data!=null || data != undefined)
        {
            $.each($.parseJSON(data).previews, function (key, value) {
                // Show tabs with navigation feature
                $('#ThumbnailTabPanel').append(
                    $('<li>').addClass('nav-item')
                        .append(
                            $('<a>').addClass('nav-link')
                                .attr('id', wsid + value.previewType + '-tab')
                                .attr('data-toggle', 'pill')
                                .attr('href', '#' + wsid + value.previewType)
                                .attr('role', 'tab')
                                .attr('aria-controls', wsid + value.previewType)
                                .attr('aria-selected', 'false')
                                .text(value.previewType)));

                // Set the contents/body of each tab
                $('#ThumbnailTabContent').append(
                    $('<div>').attr('role', 'tabpanel')
                        //.attr('style','display: block;')
                        .attr('class', 'tab-pane')
                        .attr('id', + wsid + value.previewType)
                        .attr('aria-labelledby', wsid + value.previewType + '-tab')
                        //.attr('aria-hidden','true')
                        .append(
                            //$('<span>')
                            //.attr('style', 'display: block;')
                            //.attr('id', 'span-' + value.previewType)
                            //    .append(
                                    $('<image>')
                                .attr('src', 'data:' + value.mimeType + ';base64,' + value.data)
                                .attr('style', 'display: block;height: 300px;width: 350px;'))
                //)
                );
            });

            $('#ThumbnailTabPanel a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();    
                $(this).tab('show');    // Highlight selected tab link/button
                let selectedTabId = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];    
                $('#' + selectedTabId).show(); // Show selected tab content
                $('#' + selectedTabId).find('image').show();                    
                $(this).parent().siblings().each(function () {   // Hide unselected tabs content  
                    let otherTabId = $(this).children(0).attr('id').split('-')[0];
                    $('#' + otherTabId).find('image').hide();
                    $('#' + otherTabId).hide();
                });
            });

            $('#PressSheetThumbnailModal').modal('toggle'); // Show modal with Thumbnails
        }
    }

</script>
```

[Main Modal from the _Layout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoQA5.png)

[Child Modal from DeviceTracker page - where image is not visible and rendered HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd7Lg.png)

Comment: try `<img>` instead of `<image>`

Comment: OMG! previously I was using <img> tag and somehow due to other issue removed it while trying to fix that and now as you said, <img> works perfect! Thanks for the quick solution - spent whole day to try different things...:(. 

You may add it in the answer and then I can close this. Thnx again.